# Can't select data attribute from html

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
    <div class="ac-users ac-appender">
        <div class="chip" data-id="3069243" data-text="">IBM(3069243)
            <i class="material-icons close">close</i>
        </div>
        <div class="chip" data-id="6640418" data-text="">INTC(6640418)
            <i class="material-icons close">close</i>
        </div>
        <div class="chip" data-id="1452690" data-text="">RJF(1452690)
            <i class="material-icons close">close</i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to select from this and get an array of the data-id.  $('.chip') selects the array of chips effectively, but I am not able to extract the values of data-id(s)

With jquery I am using the following but it only brings back the first item:

```
    $('.chip').attr("data-id");
```

Comment: how are you getting the `data-id`?

Comment: can you paste you jquery code here?

Comment: $('.chip').attr("data-id"); only brings back the first item

Comment: `$('.chip').data('id')`

Comment: iterate over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = $('.chip').map(function() {

  return $(this).attr('data-id');

}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ac-users ac-appender">
  <div class="chip" data-id="3069243" data-text="">IBM(3069243)
    <i class="material-icons close">close</i>
  </div>
  <div class="chip" data-id="6640418" data-text="">INTC(6640418)
    <i class="material-icons close">close</i>
  </div>
  <div class="chip" data-id="1452690" data-text="">RJF(1452690)
    <i class="material-icons close">close</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

> Description: Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataIds = $('.chip').map(function(i, chip) {
  return chip.getAttribute('data-id');
});
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank You

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$(".chip").map(function() { return $(this).data('id') } ).get();
```

It gets all elements of class "chip" then calls a function on each element to get the data-id and creates an array of the format:

[3069243, 6640418, 1452690]